# Mvn clean install is successful in terminal but fails with Intelliji 2019.3

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3, pom.xml

[image]Project build successful when built using maven 3.6.9 using mac terminal. The same when imported into Intellij IDE shows errors in POM.xml file but at the same time no compile time errors in .java class files.

Project details:
Java version : 1.8
maven version: 3.6

The above mentioned details are configured exactly same the same in IDE and terminal as well.But unsure how it is successful in terminal but fails in IDE.

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Plugins dependency not found, Parent properties cannot be inherited etc..

Comment: Could you please show `pom.xml`?

Comment: POM file is quite huge, hence unable to post

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attachd (Help | Compress Logs and Show in ...).

Comment: Sure will do post in Jetbrains